# Launch shell scripts from Jenkins

Tags: linux, shell, hudson, jenkins

I'm a complete newbie to Jenkins.
I'm trying to get Jenkins to monitor the execution of my shell script so i that i don't have to launch them manually each time but i can't figure out how to do it.
I found out about the "monitor external job" option but i can't configure it correctly.
I know that Jenkins can understand Shell script exit code so this is what i did :

```
test1(){
ls /home/user1 | grep $2
case $? in
    0) msg_error 0 "Okay."
        ;;
    *) msg_error 2 "Error."
        ;;
esac
}
```

It's a simplified version of my functions.
I execute them manually but i want to launch them from Jenkins with arguments and get the results of course.
Can this be done ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider setting up an Ant build that executes your shell scripts by using Ant's Exec command:

http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/exec.html

By setting the Exec task's **failonerror** parameter to true, you can have the build fail if your shell script returns an error code.

Answer (score 0):

To use parameters in your shell you can always send them directly. for example:

1. Define string parameter in your job Param1=test_param
2. in your shell you can use $Param1 and it will send the value "test_param"

Regarding the output, everything you do under the shell section will be only relevant to the session of the shell. you can try to return your output into a key=value txt file in the workspace and inject the results using [EnvInject Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin). Then you can access the value as if you defined it as a parameter for the job. In the example above, after injecting the file, executing shell echo $Param1 will print "test_param"

Hope it's helpful!